He hecho un dado y me fuerza a usar un "Try"
He hecho un dado para practicar algunas de las cosas que he aprendido con Java , me funciona bien (me ha costado), pero el "int tirada" se me subrayaba en amarillo y vscode me decía que lo transformara en un Try , lo cual no sé qué es.
Alguien puede explicarme por qué pasa esto?
Lo hice a pesar de que el código funcionaba , no me gusta que haya nada subrayado. (Quizá deba acostumbrarme)
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dado {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int dado;
        int tirada;
        do {
            System.out.println("Pulsa cero para tirar el dado");
            tirada = teclado.nextInt();
            dado = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
            System.out.println("El resultado del dado ha sido " + dado);
        } while (tirada == 0);

        System.out.println("Se terminó tirar el dadito");
    }

}

}

El try te ayuda a capturar excepciones (errores) que ocurran dentro del mismo, si añades un catch puedes ver la excepción que te devuelva el código dentro del try.

This question is similar to: ¿Cual es la manera correcta de cerrar conexiones y statements?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PsychoMx en este caso hace más que eso, ya que es un try con recursos
